# android libs calculated before libs are populated?

Tags: android, ant, android-build

this is a weird one. i have a `-pre-compile` target in my `custom_rules.xml`. in here, some JARs get copied into the `libs` folder.

if i do a clean build, it fails at runtime because those libraries do not get included in the .apk. looking at the output of `ant -v ...`, Dx is not processing those libs. so, while the project is being compiled against against those libraries, they are not included at the Dx phase.

if i subsequently do a non-clean `ant debug`, everything is fine, as the JARs copied by `-pre-compile` were already there at the start of the build.

any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i eventually figured this out by painstakingly adding echo statements to the `.../tools/ant/build.xml` from the SDK.

the path that includes the libraries in `.../libs` for Dx is defined in the `-setup` task. this is in the chain before `-pre-compile` or `-pre-build`, so if you copy JARs into your `.../libs` folder at either of those points, it's too late.

i ended up overriding the `-setup` task, as so,

```
  <target name="-setup" depends="-prepare-libs, android_rules.-setup"/>

  <target name="-prepare-libs">
    ... build / copy libs in to .../libs here
  </target>
```

note the syntax for calling through to the overridden `-setup` task ... the project name defined in the `project` tag  appended with the task name, as defined in the `build.xml` imported from the SDK.